# How can I design an illusion that forces a PC to do something if they fail the saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, illusion, charmed

I'm currently designing a dungeon that will try to tempt the various PCs with objects or items. Specifically, in a room with the illusion of being filled with treasure, if a PC fails a WIS saving throw when picking up one of the treasures they become obsessed with trying to fill their pockets with the room's fake riches. I'm wondering if there's an official way of having the PC effectively "charmed" by the illusion upon a failed save, as the "charmed" condition seems to apply more specifically to combat conditions.

Next, what's the best way for the PC to realise the truth? A regular WIS saving throw? Another PC to break the illusion? Some other method?

Finally, I'm looking for any ideas for the punishment for failing said WIS save, and would be keen to hear what you guys think. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What spell or effect are you using to create this illusion? Or are you trying to homebrew something? Without knowing this, I don't think we can answer it effectively.

Comment: The "charm person" spell has an effect close to what I want, but as it's not a combat scenario, I'm uncertain how being charmed would affect the PC in this case. As such, I was just planning to homebrew something. I can create my own conditions, but I'm interested to see if there is anything official covering this potential situation.

Comment: I think there's a lot of to figure out in your question before we can answer it. I'm going to upvote you to help get you to 20 Rep so that you can join [chat], and folks in there can help you focus your question. FYI, the [Charmed condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Charmed) has specific mechanical effects. Are those what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it :) I had read the Charmed condition effects, but they pertain more to combat (harmful abilities or effects) or to a "charmer", which in this case is an inanimate object. Maybe Charmed is not the best condition to use in this case, but it seemed like the closest thing to what I was looking for at the time.

Comment: You've got rep now to join [chat] if you'd like to try and figure out how to rewrite your question or help guide you to more resources if it doesn't it our format.

Comment: For some reason it's saying I don't have the 20 reputation necessary to write in the chat. I checked and I was joined to another stackexchange community with only 1 reputation, the profile for which I've since deleted after following internet advice. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85162/discussion-between-azog4-and-nautarch).